# Styling a switch how to set correct images

Tags: android

I have two graphics:

[image]

and:

[image]

the first graphic should be kind of a background of the switch but when i set it:

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_background"
```

The image is not set. there is still no background at all.
I could set the second graphic successfully using:

```
android:thumb="@drawable/custom_switch_thumb"
```

**How can i set the background of the switch?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:track="@drawable/custom_background"`

If you want to add color to your custom switch, you can also use selectors for the `track` and `thumb` and then use your coloured images in the selectors. This will allow you do provide some visual feedback of the current switch state to the user

**Update**

In your drawable folder create a file called `switch_bg.xml` with the following contents. `switch_bg_on` and `switch_bg_off` are the images used for the track. Make use of the colors you want for the on and off states.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_on" />
  <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_off" />
</selector>
```

Then create a file `switch_thumb.xml` in the drawable folder. `switch_thumb_on` and `switch_thumb_off` are images again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_on" />
  <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_off" />
</selector>
```

Then in your switch view use something like the following:

```
<Switch 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:track="@drawable/switch_bg"
   android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb" />
```

Comment: ok setting my first icon to the track works fine. you mentioned i could still use the coloring when i set my custom track? do you have an example?